# Trigger before update a fields in a table

Tags: performance

I want to know how can I code a trigger that verify a fields before updating it. For example I want to prevent a date update, let say, not to modify records with date before '2020-01-01'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this is not the case in your situation, but this strikes me as a kind of validation best done in code, before the database layer. Coding with database triggers tends to be relatively messy, and the existence of triggers is oftentimes hidden from other programmers, causing confusing behavior.

Comment: Follow the pattern set here to create such a trigger https://stackoverflow.com/a/34339282/3816779.

Comment: There are efforts to standardise RDBMS languages ([SQL/PSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/PSM)). They have not been very successful (even less than for SQL!). We'd need to see your RDBMS and some sample tables (DDL  - `CREATE TABLE foo...`, DML - `INSERT INTO foo...`) or as a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9dadc451987b6d80ecb0d21e3844ed92). I don't necessarily agree that this sort of validation should be done in the app layer - your RDBMS is the last bastion of defence of your data - use it! You can use it **with** Javascript/whatever! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Welcome to dba.stackexchange.com. A good guide to asking questions is https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer will vary depending upon the RDBMS you are using. Also DBAs & developers have different preferences.

Personally i would choose to apply this in a stored procedure rather than a trigger. Triggers dont scale well and can give unpredictable results with bulk updates.

Comment: "*and can give unpredictable results with bulk updates*" can you elaborate on that? I have never seen any "unpredictable" results with triggers (unexpected maybe, but never unpredictable). Regardless on how rows where updated or inserted. Did you have any specific DBMS product in mind with that statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unexpected may have been a better phrase. Ive had a few examples ive had to debug issues where more than one row was updated and the trigger only fired for the first row. I think later versions of sql server handle it better. Its been a while since ive had to deal with this.

Comment: This is not an issued in Postgres or Oracle, as triggers are fired per row there, not per statement (at least you can create them that way)